# json structure difference after edits

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I have json string that I have to edit and then transform back to json. But unfortunately I can't really restore the json structure.

The structure of the original json string ($json):

```
"[{"Language":{"0":"EN"},"Text":{"0":"xxx"},"ContentType":{"0":"PlainText"}},
{"Language":{"0":"DE"},"Text":{"0":"xxx"},"ContentType":{"0":"PlainText"}},
{"Language":{"0":"FR"},"Text":{"0":"xxx"},"ContentType":{"0":"PlainText"}}]"
```

The structure I get after my edits ($newJson):

```
"{"0":{"Language":{"0":"EN"},"Text":{"0":"yyy"},"ContentType":{"0":"PlainText"}},
"1":{"Language":{"0":"DE"},"Text":{"0":"yyy"},"ContentType":{"0":"PlainText"}},
"2":{"Language":{"0":"FR"},"Text":{"0":"yyy"},"ContentType":{"0":"PlainText"}}}"
```

Here is what I do with my edits:

```
$jsonArray = object_to_array(json_decode($json));
$editedJsonArray = someLoopStuff($jsonArray);
$newJson = json_encode(array_to_object(($editedJsonArray)));

function object_to_array($obj) {
    if(is_object($obj)) $obj = (array) $obj;
    if(is_array($obj)) {
        $new = array();
        foreach($obj as $key => $val) {
            $new[$key] = $this->object_to_array($val);
        }
    }
    else $new = $obj;
    return $new;
}

function array_to_object($a) {
    if (is_array($a) ) {
        foreach($a as $k => $v) {
            $a[$k] = $this->array_to_object($v);
        }
        return (object) $a;
    }
    return $a;
}
```

Do you have an idea how I could get the same structure as the original json?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use arrays instead of objects. Pass `true` to `json_decode()` as second argument and then do your stuff on arrays.

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);
```

Then just make your operation in loop on `$jsonArray` and simply use `json_encode()` without any additional work.

---

To achieve exactly same output as you have on input you need to cast subarrays on objects:

```
$jsonArray = json_decode('[{"Language":{"0":"EN"},"Text":{"0":"xxx"},"ContentType":{"0":"PlainText"}},{"Language":{"0":"DE"},"Text":{"0":"xxx"},"ContentType":{"0":"PlainText"}},{"Language":{"0":"FR"},"Text":{"0":"xxx"},"ContentType":{"0":"PlainText"}}]', true);

foreach ($jsonArray as &$item) {
    foreach ($item as &$val) {
        $val = (object) $val;
    }
    unset($val);
}
unset($item); 

var_dump(json_encode($jsonArray));
```

Output:

```
string(226) "[{"Language":{"0":"EN"},"Text":{"0":"xxx"},"ContentType":{"0":"PlainText"}},{"Language":{"0":"DE"},"Text":{"0":"xxx"},"ContentType":{"0":"PlainText"}},{"Language":{"0":"FR"},"Text":{"0":"xxx"},"ContentType":{"0":"PlainText"}}]"
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. But now I get `{"Language":["EN"],"Text":["xxx"],"ContentType":["PlainText"]}` instead of `{"Language":{"0":"EN"},"Text":{"0":"xxx"},"ContentType":{"0":"PlainText"}}`. Any idea how to fix this as well?

Answer (score 0):

What if you would try to avoid using functions object_to_array and array_to_object. In the encoding part it is not necessary, because json_encode can handle objects or arrays. In the first part json_decode can be called with second optional parameter set to true to produce array instead of object. See [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).